# Is the noun (Nancy) a subject or object in this case?

Tags: subjects, direct-objects

In the following sentence, I say that (Nancy) is a subject, but the test corrector says it is a direct object. Which one is correct?

> Here comes **Nancy**.

Comment: You're right. The test incorrector is wrong.

Comment: You are right: this is an inversion construction in which "Nancy" is the subject. It's comparable to a running commentary, describing a situation that is taking place as it unfolds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure is called *subject-verb inversion after place adverbials*, and is well described [here](http://www.grammaring.com/subject-verb-inversion-after-place-adverbials). From the name of the structure you can determine that "Nancy" is the subject, and "here" is an adverbial of place.

You can see this by reorganizing the words to their deep structure like this:

> Here Nancy comes.

Also, the verb "come" is *intransitive*, which means it cannot take a direct object.

Further, if Nancy is a direct object, then where's the subject?

The options are:

1. "Here" is the subject
2. The sentence has an implied subject

"Here" cannot be the subject because "here" can only be used as a noun after a preposition, like "*from here*", and in this sentence, it clearly is an adverb because it describes *how* something comes, in particular, where it's coming.

There is no implied subject because English only does that in particular structures like commands, like "*Come here!*, and this is not one of those structures.

So, your test corrector is wrong.

Comment: Thank you. You have convinced me

Comment: @MariaRodriguez I have added a paragraph to the top with a relevant link.